# Approval Process on Salesforce using RESTful API

Tags: salesforce

How can I use the REST APIs for the approval process on the salesforce cloud?

It is driving me crazy, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The REST API doesn't currently support any approval process operations, you'd have to use the soap API.

Comment: can u plz tell how can i use it using soap api? thanx

Comment: see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_process.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can now (since API version 30.0). See the [REST API Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_processes.htm?search_text=approval).